# custom data connector with URL as parameter for a web api

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am building the custom data connector where I have a situation to take URL as a parameter. So basically if the user finds our connectors from the market place the first step will be inputing the domain name like below

[image]

Here is my M Language Code:

```
DataSource.Kind="TConnectorPOC", Publish="TConnectorPOC.Publish"]
shared TConnectorPOC.Contents = (optional message as text) =>
    let

        source=Json.Document(Web.Contents(basicURL & endpoint )),
      #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
       #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"projectId", "parentQuoteId", "projectGroupId","projectGroupCode", "projectGroupName", "code", "name", "description", "status", "customerId","customerContactId", "templateId"})
    in
         #"Expanded Column1";
```

Basically my basicURL should prompt the first image if they open our connector.I am really having hard time to achieve this. Kindly help. thanks

Comment: Power BI already has a web source connector to get data from API/web pages. What difference does your connector achieves?

Comment: We want to build our own stand alone data connector. So our users can easily find our data connector from Power Bi desktop other data sources and they can view their enumerated dashboard instantly without going via API /web pages manually.

Comment: They will have to provide API URL anyway right? Power bi web source does the same thing you are trying to achieve with a custom connector.

Comment: The idea here is using custom connector. I will configure various endpoints, customized dashboard  and reports along with DAX formula. If you use web source to achieve this then customer has no idea which endpoints they need to connect to see a customize dashboard and reports. Hope now it is clear